# The upper bound on the number of four cycles of 3-connected quadrangulation graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, extremal-combinatorics

Recently I was thinking about a question:

- **what is the upper bound on the number of four cycles for 3-connected quadrangulation graphs with $n$ vertices?**

I use the [plantri software,](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/plantri/) and propose the following conjecture.

**Conjecture:** The maximum number of $C_4$ in a 3-connected quadrangulation graph $G$ with $n$ vertices is given by

$$
\begin{cases}
6 & n=8\\
8& n=10\\
2n-13& m\ge 11
\end{cases}
$$

Since 3-connected quadrangulation graph class seems to have a good recursive structure, mathematical induction may be useful. Some of my thoughts are as follows：

- If there is no separating 4-cycle in $G$, then the number of 4-cycles is equal to the number of 4 faces of $G$ which is $n-2$.
- If there is a separating cycle $C$ in the graph. Let $C_{int}$ be the all inner vertices of $C$ and $C_{out}$ be all outer vertices of $C$. Now  I have difficulty in proving it. For example, I can't deal with a situation  that the induced subgraph $G[V(C)\cup V(C_{int})]$ is isomorphic to a cube graph. Here we want to make inductive assumptions about subgraphs $G[V(C)\cup V(C_{out})]$ , but the problem is that $G[V(C)\cup V(C_{out})]$ is not necessarily 3-connected. We can't use induction here.

I don't know if someone solved this problem in some paper or **if it's just a simple exercise**. I don't know yet.

[image]

---

I post a related problem in MathOverflow: [Is there any study on the bounds on the number of even cycles for planar bipartite graphs?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430744/is-there-any-study-on-the-bounds-on-the-number-of-even-cycles-for-planar-biparti)

Comment: The inductive structure [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2005.10.005) might be more useful. But dealing with $P_1$-expansion is not so easy here.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I also read this article once. (I should need to reread it.) The amazing thing is that the structure of the quadrangulation graphs *looks simple* (at least with some recursion), but it's actually not simple.

Comment: @MishaLavrov The 3-connected quadrangulation graphs  are closely related to the optimal 1-planar graphs. A recent article  [Gollin, J. P., Hendrey, K., Methuku, A., Tompkins, C., & Zhang, X. (2021). Counting cliques in $1 $-planar graphs. arXiv preprint arXiv:2109.02906.] on cliques of $1$-planar graphs also mentioned the following problem: What is the
maximum number of $3$-cuts in an $n$-vertex  quadrangulation  graph?  The problem of the maximum number of $3$-cuts of quadrangulation  graphs is equivalent to the problem of the maximum number of $3$- cliques of optimal $1$-planar graphs.

Comment: @MishaLavrov These problems are striking to me that people seem to forget about the extreme  problems of such beautiful graphs.  Among the extreme problems of this graph class, the only isolated result that seems to exist at present is the Wiener index in chemical graph theory. [ Győri E, Paulos A, Xiao C. Wiener index of quadrangulation graphs[J]. Discrete Applied Mathematics, 2021, 289: 262-269. ]

Comment: A new paper on the lower bound of Wiener index on  quadrangulation graphs. [Czabarka, É., Olsen, T. V., Smith, S. J., & Székely, L. (2022). Minimum Wiener index of triangulations and quadrangulations. Discrete Applied Mathematics, 322, 295-310.]